# Temporary message "Warning - Please, select row" while switching between tabs with JQuery and JQGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have two tabs using jQuery that contains grids using jqgrid.

When I switch between tabs I get a temporary message:

> "Warning - Please, select row"

How do I fix this?

Comment: Have you have change the name of the jqgrid? Can you post you code?

Comment: Otherwise (besides switching between tabs) your grids appear fine?